# Why DNS response includes questions section?

Tags: dns

Here is a sample intermediate request and response from a recursion enabled ns query:

[image: Intermediate response]

As you can see, the response includes the questions section. But why? Is it to let the resolver match the response with the query it made? But the resolver can match the response using the ID field as well right? So why include the question section in the answer?

And here is the final request and response of the same query:

[image: Final response]
This time, the domain name requested is included both in the questions section of the response and answers section of the response. So it is duplicated double times. What is the purpose of this? Why duplicate the information?

The way I think is, both in the intermediate response and the final response, the questions section could be omitted since we have the ID field. Furthermore, there is double duplication in the final response in the answers section.

So could you explain why it was required to duplicate the information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNS traditionally operates over UDP, a connectionless protocol, so a response cannot indicate via network information what request it is in response to.

Providing the question allows a server performing a recursive query to send the response on to the correct querant, to pass the datagram on to hosts without modifying it, and allows advanced firewalls to determine that a given udp datagram incoming on 53 is part of a solicited request-response pair.

Since UDP cannot convey this information, it is up to the application to define its data structure such that it can perform the task.

See section 4.1.1 of [RFC 1035](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1035.html) for descriptions of each of the elements in the message structure. In particular for ID:

> ID
>   A 16 bit identifier assigned by the program that
>                   generates any kind of query.  This identifier is copied
>                   the corresponding reply and can be used by the requester
>                   to match up replies to outstanding queries.

So, ID is how the end-user workstation box can tell which app requested the lookup. This might be important if multiple apps are making requests in a narrow window. This information would only be pertinent to the machine generating the request, since it arbitrarilly assigns the ID, and no other application or server or system knows what it is. ID collissions are therefor likely.

Comment: But then what is the use of the ID field?

Comment: See my edits. The answers you are looking for are all in the RFC1035 in section 4.1.1.